# After mbr2gpt conversion, Windows 10 system cannot boot

Tags: windows-10, boot, mbr, gpt

Before I ran mbr2gpt my Windows 10 PC had MBR partition with two volumes: one System Reserve partition (2G), one OS partition(236G). After I ran

mbr2gpt /convert /disk:0 /allowFullOS

A third partition was created. The running information showed the conversion was completed successfully. When I tried to reboot it to change firmware to UEFI boot, bad thing happened: Windows Boot Manager prompted \Boot\BCD had an 0xc000000f error. Then I changed firmware to boot from UEFI, a blue screen that showed "Registry Error" appeared.

I believe some thing happened to System Reserved partition, but I don't know how to fix it. I tried to use bootrec to repair BCD, but failed.

I would appreciate any idea which can help fix this issue.

Comment: You normally run this application before changing your computer firmware (uefi) from "legacy" or "compatibility support" mode to full UEFI mode. Have you switched your motherboard to UEFI? Windows cannot boot a GPT disk in BIOS mode nor can it boot an MBR disk in UEFI mode, it is simply not supported by the bootloader.

Comment: I just found the mbr2gpt conversion process was disturbed by Sophos, an anti-virus application. There should be some important files deleted by it during the conversion. Tried to find out what Sophos actually did in this process.

Comment: Restore your full HDD from the last disk image.